# How does the author concludes that $f^{-1} (V)$ is open?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

In the book of *Topology* by Munkres, at page 128, it is given that

[image]
[image]

However how can the author conclude that

if $B(x,\delta)$ is a neighbourhood of x contained in $f^{-1} (V)$, then $f^{-1} (V)$ is open ? I mean $x$ is arbitrary, and we have found a ball around $x$ contained in $f^{-1} (V)$, but I can't see how does it mean that $f^{-1} (V)$ is open.

Comment: A subset $U$ of a metric space if open iff for all $x\in U$, there is $r>0$ such that $B(x,r)\subseteq U$.

Comment: It’s the *definition* of an open set in the metric topology.

Comment: Or use the statement on p 118 middle.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Theorem about the standard bounded metric ?

Comment: No, in the original edition of Munkres this says: "A set $U$ is open in the metric topology induced by $d$ if and only if for each $y \in U$, there is a $\delta >0$ such that $B_d(y,\delta) \subset U$."

Comment: In the 2nd edition this statement is on p120, underneath figure 20.1

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Ok, thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each $B(x,\delta)$ is open and $f^{-1}(V) = \cup_{x \in f^{-1}(V)} B(x,\delta)$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall the first definition at the beginning of Chapter 20 - The Metric Topology:

> **Definition:** If $d$ is a metric on a set $X$, then the collection of all $\epsilon$-balls $B_d(x, \epsilon)$, for $x \in X$ and $\epsilon > 0$, is a basis for a topology on $X$, called the **metric topology induced by $d$**.

Using the definition of a basis, this means that:

> A set $U$ is open in the metric topology induced by $d$ iff for each $x \in U$, there is some $\epsilon> 0$ such that $B_d(x, \epsilon) \subseteq U$.

Comment: In the 2nd edition this is on page 120, under figure 20.1